# Does Firebase include domain name while caching content from functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using request.hostname in functions to serve different content for the same url.pathname. If I set Cache-Control to cache the content in CDN, will it be cached by url.pathname or request.hostname+url.pathname? i.e. will it serve the same the content across different domains because of caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching is specific to the complete URL, not just to the path.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, do you see any problem if I use request.hostname to serve different content for the same path under different domain names?